# Azure SQL bacpac import job stuck - timeout on it?

Tags: azure, sql, azure-sql

Got some issues with a stuck azure sql bacpac import preventing me from importing the bacpac again to the database with the same name.

The file is being pulled in from an Azure storage account.  I was importing a bacpac file (575mb) of a database that's 16gb.  I thought the database import had stalled and deleted the database that was created as part of the import.  Since discovered that the import was still in flight.

Now when i try and create another import of the database with the same name.

I've tried running `az sql db op list` to list the job but as the database no longer exists it errors (i deleted it thinking it had failed but the jobs still there in the background).

Also tried the same via the Microsoft API - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databaseoperations/cancel but that gives a 404 as the database isn't there.

Anyone any idea on how I can cancel the stuck job?

No support on the account at the moment so my idea of contacting MS has gone.  Is there a timeout on the job?

Comment: I have the same issue, ImportToNewDatabase stuck at Running, Progress = 1 % for over a week now. It is based on premium P6 so I'm afraid it will suddenly succeed and then we have to pay over 100 dollar a day..

Did you resolve it?

Comment: Anyone found a solution?

Comment: Ended up just leaving it for a few days to clear up

Comment: and what happened after?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post - I just had a similar issue:  I was trying to import a bacpac from azure storage via private link.  It was stuck at 1% for ages.  I then found that I had to authorise the private link connection on both sides (sql server and storage account).

This can be done in the networking blade of each service under private link, but it did take a little bit of time for these to appear there.  Once I authorised both sides the % complete grew at a reasonable rate.

Comment: Please update the answers, including commands and references. You can also find tips here: [answer]